# Why is require not defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have been watching [this video](https://youtu.be/sRWE5tnaxlI) where they show how the any javascript code can be expressed using only the characters `({[/>+!-=\]})`. The video shows how to program a compiler which converts from regular js to js with only the aforementioned characters. I have managed to get this to work for most code. However, when I try to use `require` in the input program (a program which I have tested to be completely working), it breaks when converted into the characters, showing the following error message:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Matthew Miles\Documents\Programming_stuff\JS\output.js:1:279), <anonymous>:6:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Matthew Miles\Documents\Programming_stuff\JS\output.js:1:6713121)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

This is problematic because my goal is to compile the compiler itself, which requires access to the module `fs`, into the special character only format. Hence, this is both my program and my input file:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { exit } = require('process');

const zero = '+[]';
const one = '+!![]';

const num = n => {if (n === 0) return zero; else return Array.from({length:n}, () => one).join(' + ');};

const map = {};
const fromString = s => s.split('').map(x => {
    if (!(x in map)) {
        const charCode = x.charCodeAt(0);
        return `([]+[])[${fromString('constructor')}][${fromString('fromCharCode')}](${num(charCode)})`;
    }
    return map[x];
}).join('+');

const NaN = '(+{}+[])';
const objObj = '({}+[])';
const false_ = '(![]+[])';
const true_ = '(!![]+[])';
const Infinity = '((+!![]/+[])+[])';

map.N = NaN+`[${num(0)}]`;
map.a = NaN+`[${num(1)}]`;
map['['] = objObj+`[${num(0)}]`;
map.o = objObj+`[${num(1)}]`;
map.b = objObj+`[${num(2)}]`;
map.j = objObj+`[${num(3)}]`;
map.e = objObj+`[${num(4)}]`;
map.c = objObj+`[${num(5)}]`;
map.t = objObj+`[${num(6)}]`;
map[' '] = objObj+`[${num(7)}]`;
map.O = objObj+`[${num(8)}]`;
map[']'] = objObj+`[${num(14)}]`; 
map.f = false_+`[${num(0)}]`;
map.l = false_+`[${num(2)}]`;
map.s = false_+`[${num(3)}]`;
map.t = true_+`[${num(0)}]`;
map.r = true_+`[${num(1)}]`;
map.u = true_+`[${num(2)}]`;
map.I = Infinity+`[${num(0)}]`;
map.n = Infinity+`[${num(1)}]`;
map.f = Infinity+`[${num(2)}]`;
map.i = Infinity+`[${num(3)}]`;
map.y = Infinity+`[${num(7)}]`;
map.S = `([]+([]+[])[${fromString('constructor')}])[${num(9)}]`;
map.g = `([]+([]+[])[${fromString('constructor')}])[${num(14)}]`;
map.p = `([]+(/-/)[${fromString('constructor')}])[${num(14)}]`;
map['\\'] = `(/\\\\/+[])[${num(1)}]`;
const getLCLetter = n => {return `(${num(n)})[${fromString('toString')}](${num(n+1)})`}
map.d = getLCLetter(13);
map.h = getLCLetter(17);
map.m = getLCLetter(22);
map.C = `(()=>{})[${fromString('constructor')}](${fromString('return escape')})()(${map['\\']})[${num(2)}]`;

const compile = code => `(()=>{})[${fromString('constructor')}](${fromString(code)})()`;

fs.readFile('./input.js', 'utf8', (err, code) => {
    if (err) {console.error(err); return;}
    console.log(code);
    console.log(compile(code).length);
    fs.writeFile('./output.js', compile(code), error => {
        if(error)console.error(error)
        console.log("done");
        process.exit();
    });
})
```

the program requires two files in the same directory as the console/program to work, `input.js` and `output.js`.

This is definitely the weirdest question I have ever asked here, but in the one in a million chance someone knows what's going on, I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it may be to do with the fact that the compiler sends the code through the function constructor. The output is actually

```js
(()=>{})['constructor']("/*code as string*/")()
```